# writing function that has implicit column names with dplyr

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I am trying to use dplyr for creating a function that takes a grepl input to filter "Source" column in a given dataframe and summarizes as a sum of "Money" column.

```
sum_sessions <- function(x, matchex01) x %>%
  filter(grepl("matchex01", Source)) %>%
  summarise(sum(Money))
```

However the sum_sessions(dataframe, "organic") gives 0 as output.But when I use:

```
x %>%
  filter(grepl("matchex01", Source)) %>%
  summarise(sum(Money))
```

It gives the correct answer.
I also tried to use filter_() but it didn't work. And the error output was:

> Error in grepl("matchex01", Source) : object 'Source' not found

Basically I'm using a sample dataframe as:

```
Source  Money
organic 20.45
direct  30.98
e-mail  67.23 
aff_pp  32.09
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a sample of your data.

Comment: Use `filter_` instead of `filter` in your function. `dplyr` uses "non-standard evaluation" by default, but using it inside a function requires use of "standard evaluation". Each dplyr verb has a standard evaluation equivalent that has the underscore on the end. See the [non-standard evaluation vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) for more info.

Comment: You have the argument name `matchex01` in quotes within the function.  This means you are always matching to the character string `"matchex01"` rather than the string you pass to the function argument.

Comment: @Edu I edited the question by adding a sample of dataframe that I'm trying to test my function.

Comment: @eipi10 I've already used that underscores, but it gave the error that I have written on the question.

Comment: @aosmith Thanks for the warning/information :)

Comment: Didn't that fix your issue?  Your function works for fine me if you remove the quotes from around `"matchex01"` in the function.

Comment: @aosmith Thanks a lot, it worked.